# Query table by indexes from integer array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

After I get excellent results with converting data "to_timestamp" and "to_number" from VB.NET I am wondering if PostgreSQL have possibility to query table indexes by array of integers from .NET?

Say, I have array filled with `(1, 3, 5, 6, 9)`.
Is here any possibility that PostgreSQL return rows with data from those indexes to "odbc.reader"?
That would be much faster than looping and querying 5 times like I do now.

Something like this:

```
SELECT myindexes, myname, myadress from mytable WHERE myindexes IS IN ARRAY
```

If this is possible how a simple query should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible.

#### ANY

```
SELECT myindex, myname, myadress
FROM   mytable
WHERE  myindex = ANY ($my_array)
```

Example with integer-array:

```
...
WHERE  myindex = ANY ('{1,3,5,6,9}'::int[])
```

[Details about `ANY` in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18025)

#### IN

There is also the SQL [`IN()` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN17987) for the same purpose.
PostgreSQl in its current implementation transforms that to `= ANY (array)` internally prior to execution, so it's conceivably a bit slower.

---

Examples for joining to a *long* list (as per comment):

#### JOIN to VALUES expression

```
WITH x(myindex) AS (
    VALUES
    (1),(3),(5),(6),(9)
    )
SELECT myindex, myname, myadress
FROM   mytable
JOIN   x USING (myindex)
```

I am using a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) in the example (which is optional, could be a sub-query as well). You need PostgreSQL 8.4 of later for that.
[The manual about `VALUES`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html)

#### JOIN to unnested array

Or you could [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) an array and `JOIN` to it:

```
SELECT myindex, myname, myadress
FROM   mytable
JOIN  (SELECT unnest('{1,3,5,6,9}'::int[]) AS myindex) x USING (myindex)
```

Each of these methods is *far superior* in performance to running a separate query per value.

Comment: Thank you very much. This probably mean that I should "write" my array to string with comas to be able to put it in a query. But I didn't find in the manual how long that array could be in bytes or elements?

Comment: @user973238: There is practically no limit to the length of the array.

Comment: That mean no limit to the length of query string. Regarding your experience is this function acceptable fast if array have few thousand elements?

Comment: @user973238: It's pretty fast. Whether performance is acceptable is for you to decide. For huge lists if may be faster to create a temporary table and `JOIN` to it, or use a `VALUES` expression for the same purpose. Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. I'll add a example queries to my answer.

Comment: I am a bit limited with that because I uses postgre through visual basic net and ODBC and where I should everything convert to string first, but I'll try all what I can to test those, new options for me.

Comment: ["Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", no such thing as "Postgre".](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)