# Postgres using two indexes for WHERE clause in parallel

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-design, postgresql-performance

I have table which has a few billion rows. There are  two columns in the table:

```
match_id uuid,
group_id integer
```

And there are indexes created on both of the above columns:

```
create index if not exists my_tbl_match_id_idx on my_tbl (match_id);
create index if not exists my_tbl_group_id_idx on my_tbl (group_id);
```

When I perform following query, both indexes are scanned in parallel.
match_id index look up is much faster and returns result back in 13 **milliseconds** while `group_id` index look up is slower and takes 1.3 **seconds**. Because both indexes are looked up in parallel, overall query time = 1.3 seconds i.e. look up time of group_id index.

Is there any way Postgres can just use `group_id` index after the `match_id` result set is computed?

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE match_id = 'e089e0af-543b-45d5-abbf-22c6c5ed9a01'
AND (group_id IN (167,1704,1864,2065,2145,3812,3814,3855,7462,11393,11394,11396))
```

**Or** do I need to create a composite index for `match_id` and `group_id`?

Comment: usually you would make a combined combined index,

Comment: I see. My query pattern is what I mentioned in the question above but also just on `match_id` i.e. SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE match_id = 'e089e0af-543b-45d5-abbf-22c6c5ed9a01' hopefully composite index won't affect adversely on this query pattern

Comment: you  can ry it only with the combined if the other query get slower you can add always more indexes, but too many make inserts and update  slower

Comment: I don't think the parallelization you describe actually exists in PostgreSQL.  Please show us the plan, not your interpretation of the plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors with bearing on the best course of action, most of which are not clear from the question. Consider instructions for [postgresql-performance](/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Generally speaking, a multicolumn index on `(match_id, group_id)` (with leading `match_id`!) performs substantially better for your query than combining two separate indexes in bitmap index scans.

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)

In effect, this index implements your requirement **exactly**:

> Is there any way Postgres can just use `group_id` index after the `match_id` result set is computed?

A multicolumn index is sorted by leading expressions first. Using this index, Postgres excludes the lion share of irrelevant matches on `group_id` for your query. Should be particularly impactful for your case since `match_id` seems to be much more selective.

See:

- [What is a "bitmap index"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869155/what-is-a-bitmap-index/19869655#19869655)
- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)

This index also covers queries on just `match_id` like you mentioned in your comment. Since `match_id` is the more selective and bigger column (`uuid` = 16 bytes, int = 4 bytes), the multicolumn index isn't much bigger than the one on just `(match_id)`, and should work almost as well for the purpose, making the overhead for maintaining a second index questionable. The other index on just `(group_id)` may still serve its purpose for queries on just `group_id`.

See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

#### Other advice

Your query can benefit a lot from physically clustering rows on `match_id`. Use `CLUSTER` or one of the less blocking community tools. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)

Only reasonable if there isn't too much write activity on the table (or large parts of it).

Also, if you don't really need `SELECT *`, but only a small subset of columns, there is potential for optimization.