# Fastest way to select a lot of rows based on their ID in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, libpqxx, rdbms

I am using postgres with libpqxx, and I have a table that we will simplify down to

```
data_table
{
  bytea id PRIMARY KEY,
  BigInt size
}
```

If I have a set of ID's in cpp, eg `std::unordered_set<ObjectId> Ids`, what is the best way to get the ID and the Size parameters out of data_table?

I have so far used a prepared statement:
`constexpr char* preparedStatement = "SELECT size FROM data_table WHERE id = $1";`

Then in a transaction I have called that prepared statement for every entry in the set, and retrieved the result for every entry in the set,

```
pqxx::work transaction(SomeExistingPqxxConnection);
std::unordered_map<ObjectId, uint32_t> result;
for (const auto& id : Ids)
{
  auto transactionResult = transaction.exec_prepared(preparedStatement, ToPqxxBinaryString(id));
  result.emplace(id, transactionResult[0][0].as<uint32_t>());
}
return result;
```

Because the set can contain tens of thousands of objects, and the table can contain millions, this can take quite some time to process, and I don't think it is a particularly efficient use of postgres.

I am pretty much brand new to SQL, so I don't really know if what I am doing is the right way to go about this, or if this is a much more efficient way.

E: For what it's worth the ObjectId class is basically a type wrapper over std::array<uint8_t, 32>, aka a 256 bit cryptographic hash.

Answer (score 1):

The task as I understand it:

*Get `id` (PK) and `size` (bigint) for "tens of thousands of objects" from a table with millions of rows and presumably several more columns ("simplified down").*

The fastest way of retrieval is **index-only scans**. The cheapest way to get that in your particular case would be a "covering index" for your query by "including" the `size` column in the PK index like this (requires Postgres 11 or later):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE data_table (
  id   bytea
, size bigint 
, PRIMARY KEY (id) INCLUDE (size)  -- !
)
```

About covering indexes:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)

Then retrieve all rows in a single query (or few queries) for many IDs at once like:

```
SELECT id, size
FROM   data_table
JOIN  (
    VALUES ('id1'), ('id2') -- many more 
    ) t(id) USING (id);
```

Or one of the other methods laid out here:

- [Query table by indexes from integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171720/query-table-by-indexes-from-integer-array/14172526#14172526)

Or create a temporary table and join to it.
**But** do *not* "insert all those IDs one by one into it". Use the much faster `COPY` (or the meta-command `\copy` in psql) to fill the temp table. See:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)

And you do *not* need an index on the temporary table, as that one will be read in a sequential scan anyway. You only need the covering PK index I lined out.

You may want to `ANALYZE` the temporary table after filling it, to give Postgres some column statistics to work with. But as long as you get the index-only scans I am aiming for, you can skip that, too. The query plan won't get any better than that.

Answer (score 0):

The id is a primary key and so is indexed, so my first concern would be query setup time.  A stored procedure is precompiled, for instance.  A second tack is to put your set in a temp table, possibly also keyed on the id, so the two tables/indexes can be joined in one select.  The indexes for this should be ordered, like tree not hash, so they can be merged.

Comment: I did consider a temp table, but I was not sure if it would be faster to insert all those IDs one by one into it then do a join.

Comment: You can insert many at a time using insert select union select, say 128 at a time for 99+% savings.  Many RDBMS have bulk import tools to load tables, which you might popen() and write to.  I worked with an Oracle JAVA app that sent 4K rows at a time in an object that could be cast to a table for insert (into many tables using the Oracle multi-table insert).  In Interbase, I wrote some UDFs and a stored procedure that together allowed me to cast a file as a table: the udfs opened the file first, read lines in the where to EOF and returned fields while the stored procedure generated fake rows.

Comment: You can also query 128 at a time, for instance in a join to a derived table of (select constant union select constant...).  This cuts your setup time to <1%.  Some RDBMS have facilities to cast a flat file as a table.  In a google world, you have to imagine it to google for it to find it!  So may ways to . . . .